# How to tell if Rsync transfer has finished from the remote computer?

Tags: rsync

If I am transferring a file or a directory form Computer A to Computer B, is there a way for me to tell (when SSH'd in to computer B) that the transfer is

A. Complete

or

B. Finished with an error of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe the output of rsync using ssh into a text file on Computer B :

```
rsync <file> user@computerB:~ 2>&1 | ssh user@computerB "cat > rsynclog.txt"
```

Then use tail or less to monitor the rsynclog.txt file